# Como criar plugins no Sizzle?

Tags: javascript

Estou a procura de alguma forma de criar plugins no [Sizzle JS](http://sizzlejs.com). Procurei muito e não achei um bom tutorial e nem alguém que me explique.

Comment: É legal você saber que o Sizzle é somente uma biblioteca que faz parte do jQuery. Ela é responsável por fazer a seleção de elementos DOM em browser que não possuem API mais modernas. Que tipo de plugins você estava pensando em criar?

Comment: Queria fazer plugins do tipo: ".home:display(inline)", ".home:inline" e se tiver outro também seria bom :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta, sem jquery

exemplo de extensão de filtros:

```
Sizzle.selectors.filters.vazio = function( elem ) {
    return elem.childElementCount === 0;
};
```

[um exemplo funcional no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/letanure/gYk4s/2/)

segundo a documentação, pode-se extender

- Seletores:

  ```
  Sizzle.selectors.find.NAME = function( match, context, isXML ) {}
  ```
- Filtros:

  ```
  Sizzle.selectors.preFilter.NAME = function( match ) {}
  ```

  ou

  ```
  Sizzle.selectors.filter.NAME: function( element, match1[, match2, match[3], ...]
  ```
- Atributos:

  ```
  Sizzle.selectors.attrHandle.LOWERCASE_NAME = function( elem, casePreservedName, isXML ) {}
  ```
- Pseudo Selectors:

  ```
  Sizzle.selectors.pseudos.NAME = function( elem ) {}
  ```

[Documentação completa](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation)

Comment: Nossa, **obrigado** \o/ Se não for pedir muito, queria um exemplo de como eu uso cada um rsrsrs.

Comment: Seu segundo item ("Filtros") não seria algo como `Sizzle.selectors.filters.NAME`? (você repetiu `find`) E os parâmetros da função são os mesmos ou não? (no seu primeiro exemplo o argumento era `elem`, no segundo os argumentos eram `match, context, isXML`)

Comment: ta certo @mgibsonbr . corrigir

Answer (score 2):

Conferindo a documentação [aqui](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#wiki-api), achei que o mais fácil é:

JS:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
  inline: function(elemento) {
    console.log(elemento, $(elemento).css('display'))
    return $(elemento).css('display') === 'inline';
  }
});
$(':inline').addClass('mostra-inline');
```

HTML para testes:

```
<div id="teste">
  <div class="inline">essa DIV é inline porque o CSS definiu</div>
  <br><br>
  <span>esse SPAN é inline por default</span>
  <br><br>
  <div>DIVs sao block</div>
</div>
```

veja um exemplo funcional no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/letanure/gYk4s/)

Comment: Luiz, assim você está usando o jQuery, minha intenção é soment usar o Sizzle =P Mas obrigado por responder

Comment: Nunca fiz com sizzle puro. dar uma olha e posto a resposta